# Why does this iterative trie-traversal not produce the correct word upon a query?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, data-structures, trie

So, here’s my predicament: I’m trying to traverse through a trie data structure to find the nth word.

For those of you unfamiliar, a trie is a compression-based data structure that allows you to insert a series of words, and sort them lexicographically, but have each node be it’s own individual letter, and thus branching off and spelling into the respective words (if it’s unclear, someone who has a more concrete definition, please fix!).

Each node in the tree has an array of 26 nodes to represent the 26 letters of the alphabet. Once a word is spelled out, a Boolean value in the array (isWord) for the last character in the word is flagged as true. This is also the case for words within words such as {a, and, are, art}; “a” is a word, therefore, isWord for this letter is set to true. However, the letters within “and” are tacked onto “a”, and the “d” is flagged as a word.

Now that the introduction is set, here’s my problem: it’s very hard for me to do this recursively, so I tried to do it iteratively. I’m very, very close to the solution, but for some reason, some words are being skipped when I call nthWord(int n). In essence, the method is supposed to traverse through the tree (which is in alphabetical order by the property of the trie) and find the nth word as the name implies. But, as aforesaid, sometimes the method skips over words in the trie, even though it’s guaranteed they’re being added to the trie (and the isWord Boolean is also always correct). I’ve been at this problem for about 3 days now, and I’m so lost.

I expect the output to be the nth word in the sequence (from a very large .txt file of words), but sometimes, it skips certain words. If j is assigned to -1, words like "aardvark" that start with 2 of the same letter are accounted for, but others are skipped. Conversely, if it's assigned to 0, other words are accounted for, but words that start with two of the same letter are skipped.

EDIT: I should also state that the nthWord(...) method doesn’t process duplicate words. Trie’s store frequencies of each word in the last character of said word. Therefore, duplicate words aren’t a problem in this instance.

Comment: Would you be averse to adding a `num_descendants` field? That would make this operation faster and easier.

Comment: A number of descendants to represent how many children a node has? How would that make it easier? Also, I’m curious as to how it can be implemented because I’d have to travel back up the tree as I add characters in order to increase the “number of descendants” variable...

Comment: You'd never have to ascend.

Comment: How? I’m confused by what you mean.

Comment: @JoshuaCrotts I think your `Node` structure is insufficient. How do you decide if a character(a.k.a Node) belongs to the `n` th word?

Comment: @vivek_23 Through the “search” boolean; it keeps track of what word I’m on. If I find a word, I compare the search value to the key. If they’re equal, I return the word (which is being constructed by my StringBuilder as I traverse the trie), else, I increment search.

Comment: @JoshuaCrotts Can you define what is `n` th word? Is it the `n` th word you added to trie, or is it `n` th word after complete trie construction? If it's the former one, just use a map.

Comment: It’s the nth word after completion. Since we’re not guaranteed that the words are in order upon creation, I can’t assume that. The nth word is defined as the word at position n if the words are in alphabetical order. I have to traverse the tree to do this; I can’t just use an array or something.

Comment: @JoshuaCrotts What does "nth word" mean?

Comment: @Rohan Suppose I have the words {a, are, art, fan, Fanny, off, offer, options}. If I create a trie off these words, and call nthWord(3), it should return art.

Comment: @JoshuaCrotts What should be the answer of `nthWord(1)` for `[azzz,abcd,aefg]` ?

Comment: @JoshuaCrotts If hunt is for alphabetical order, sorting the array of strings should be enough.

Comment: the answer would be azzz (it’s 1-indexed). We can’t use an array; we have to traverse the trie to find the nth word.

Comment: If it's 1-indexed, doesn't abcd come lexicographically before azzz. I am not sure I understand

Comment: @Rohan yes it would, that was my bad.

Comment: @JoshuaCrotts In that case, you could just sort or use a TreeMap with some additional attributes to track the `n` th. However, since you want to have `compression`, your `Node` class can be made more compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a recursive solution to this question (which is more intuitive). Just treat this like a tree problem where you have to traverse the tree left to right and try find the **N**th word.

You can DFS from the root node. Keep a variable to store the number of words you have visited so far (the number of nodes with isWord you have visited). And return the word when you reach the **N**th word.

Code would be something like this. I have just written a template code -

```
def findWord(TrieNode,word):
    global N
    if TrieNode.isWord:
        if N == 0:
            return word
        else:
            N -= 1

    for each in TrieNode.children:
        if each is not None:
            word += each.character
            res = findWord(N,each,word)
            if len(res) > 0:
                return res
            word = word[:-1]
    return ''
N = input()
findWord(root,'')
```

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that I don’t have a “children” variable per se; it’s not a linked list, it’s an array (with unused letters assigned to null) of nodes. Could I loop from 0 to 25 instead (since each node has an array of 26 nodes)?

Comment: In your case you have letters[], I am essentially iterating over an array of Nodes there.

Comment: You’re right, I’ll try this and see if it works. I’ll report back soon!

Comment: Cool let me know, if you are not a Python person and you need more explanation about any line of code

Comment: Okay, here's what I got: https://pastebin.com/az7ed9y4 

Every time I run the method, it always returns null :( it does the same thing it did when I tried to make my recursive solution.

Comment: That's because your ``search`` variable never becomes 0. Observe how I have used N in my code and I decrement it everytime I see a new word.

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake. It's still causing the same problem though: https://pastebin.com/RS5tv9cp

Comment: 2 things - 1, I don't understand why variables ``search`` and ``k`` in your function are there in your code. Just use k globally and decrement it when you find a word. 2, you have to go through all the children even though you reach a node which isn't a word

Comment: That was it! I believe I have it working now! A couple of my words that we have to test aren’t aligning properly, but I believe that’s because the words are out of order or something in the text document we’re loading in. Thanks!